# Yolo v1 single class single box training

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, object-detection, loss-function, yolo

I'm rather new to [CNNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) and object detection models.
For this reason I'm trying to implement an object detection model based on [YOLO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_detection#Methods) v1 from scratch.

My idea is to have S = 7 cells an just B = 1 box per cell.
Furthermore, I'm only interested in detecting one class. Each cell then contains a prediction like [P, x, y, w, h] and y_train has dimensions [7x7x5].

I'm implementing the model on [Colaboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Industry_adoption) with [Keras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras). The full code can be found in my GitHub repository: "https://github.com/frapasti/Human-Hands.git"

I've deeply studied the paper.

My problem is that the loss diverges early in the training and the model outputs only NaN.

Here's the custom loss that I've used:

```
import keras.backend as K

def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
  yes_obj = y_true[..., 0]

  lxy = K.sum((K.square(y_pred[..., 1] - y_true[..., 1]) + K.square(y_pred[..., 2] - y_true[..., 2]))*yes_obj)
  lwh = K.sum((K.square(K.sqrt(y_pred[..., 3]) - K.sqrt(y_true[..., 3])) + K.square(K.sqrt(y_pred[..., 4]) - K.sqrt(y_true[..., 4])))*yes_obj)
  lp = K.sum(K.square(y_true[..., 0] - y_pred[..., 0])*yes_obj)

  return lxy + lwh + lp

yolo.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
yolo.fit(X_train, Y_train, batch_size=25, epochs=5, verbose=1)
```

I really don't understand why...
I've skipped the pre-training of the convolutional layer on just classification, but I don't think that's what causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if it is a gradient divergence problem. Did you implement the custom loss from the YOLO v1 paper? I'm trying to do the same. However, I am getting not-so-good results with the model.

Training results:

[image: 1]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73308805/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.